# Remote connection to RedHat virtual machine from other PCs in the network

Tags: rhel, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed a virtual machine `RHEL 6.1` using `Oracle Virtual Box` on my `Windows 7` Computer.

I have set the network options to Bridged adapter mode, my host Computer (Win-7) is connected on my home network via statically assigned IP =192.168.25.1, so I set the IP on the RHEL virtual machine = 192.168.25.2. I have also Enabled Server on Remote Display options (Server port 3389, Authentication Null, Timeout 5000, Allowed multiple connections) on the virtual machine settings.

The remote access option is also enabled on the Virtual Machine RHEL and disabled the Firewall  as well on the VM. But still I am unable to access the VM remotely from another computer on the network IP = 192.168.25.3 using VNC.

I can successfully ping from the VM to both the Host Win7 as well as the other Win7 PC on the network. But I cant Ping to the VM from the Win7 PCs.

Any clues regarding the solution ???

The screenshot of ifconfig -a is shown below. During this test scenario the host machine is 192.168.25.50 (which can be taken on remote using MSTSC from anothe PC on the network). And the RHEL VM is given IP 192.168.25.15.

[image]

Comment: In the RHEL VM, can you type in `ipconfig -a | less` and display the results?

Comment: From 192.168.25.3, if you do `telnet 192.168.25.2 3389`, do you get connected, or timed out?

Comment: Is this new RHEL added to the known hosts file of all the windows machine? I suspect that might be an issue.

Comment: I am getting timed out if i try to telnet from 192.168.25.3

Comment: I dont know how to add the RHEL VM to known hosts file... kindly guide...

Comment: Please refer to the manual here. http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1821155/edit-hosts-file-windows.html

Comment: What happens if you change the network settings to NAT in VirtualBox?

Comment: I tried using NAT also but still no help...

Comment: HEY, I used the manual at the link you gave.. It worked. VNC is working after I put the VM IP in the known hosts file.. Thank You.